# How to use Stokes Theorem here?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

I think we have to use the Stoke's Theorem here.

So let $F=(-y^3+xz)i+(yz+x^3)j+(z^2)k$. Then Curl $F=-yi+xj+3(x^2+y^2)k$. Now $\int \int_S Curl F.n dS=\int_C F.dr=$The integral we have to compute. But I am confused how $S$ looks like. How do we find $n$ and $dS$? Can somebody please help me?

Comment: It looks something like this - [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SlBBU.png).

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use Stokes theorem to calculate this integral. Just find proper parametriztion. If you won't be able to find one, let me know. I can provide you with the parameters I used to generate that plot above.